# How to write a Rust function with argument that accept both of *const and *mut pointer

Tags: rust

I'm trying to find out how to write a function that receives both of `*const` and `*mut` pointer. Rust doesn't seems to have a trait for pointers. Is there a solution in latest version of Rust?

Here is an example, the function needs a pointer, but not care about the mutability of the pointer.

```
use std::ffi::c_void;
fn main() {
    let const_ptr = 0usize as *const c_void; // null const pointer
    function(const_ptr);
    let mut_ptr = 0usize as *mut c_void; // null mut pointer
    function(mut_ptr);

}
fn function<T>(arg: *ANY T) -> *ANY T {
    arg
}
```

Comment: One of them is mutable other is constant, what is the actual need to create a common function to handle shared behavior between **immutable** and **mutable** ? If you'll evaluate under immutable behaviors you can simply define your function like this: `function<T>(arg: *const T) -> *const T`

Comment: I'll add to @ÖmerErden's comment that Rust allows you to cast seamlessly between `*mut T` and `*const T`, so a function should really only declare to take the one of these two pointers that fits its needs.

Comment: @ÖmerErden Generally false. The difference between `*const T` and `*mut T` is mostly stylistic.

Comment: What do you want to do with the pointer?

Comment: @ÖmerErden the only difference I know between the two (besides the fact that they're not the same type in a signature) is their variance. `*const T` is covariant, whereas `*mut T` is invariant.

Comment: @BlackBeans to talk about the variance of a type, specify the variance over what

Comment: @AlexVergara `*const T` and `*mut T` only have a single type parameter, so no, you don't need to specify variance over what, since there is only one option anyway.

Comment: @BlackBeans The main difference between const and mut pointers is whether dereferencing results in a mutable place expression.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman What I wanted to emphasize was how rust behaves on implicit casting, do you think this is a bug then? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c0a36a442104ebf022b3f65c04cd35ff , or this happens because of the variance? since same applies `&T` and `&mut T`, well If it is because of the variance then I don't expect explicit casting would work tho

Comment: Coercion is only performed from `mut` to `const`, that's true, but it's fine to cast explicitly. References are another story.

Answer (score 1):

`Rust` does not support any kind of direct overload in their fn or method signatures. But as always, exists and idiomatic *way to go*. This is, go with traits.

```
trait Pointereable {}

fn accept_diff_pointers<T: Pointereable>(ptr: T) { // do stuff }
```

Then, you have to implement that new trait for the desired types:

```
impl Pointereable for X {}
impl Pointereable for Y {}
...
```

and so on and so forth, where in this example, `X` and `Y` are the exact pointer types that you want to work with.

One last note:

Cast `const` things to `mut` ones is `Undefined Behaviour`.

> Transmuting an & to &mut is Undefined Behavior. While certain usages may appear safe, note that the Rust optimizer is free to assume that a shared reference won't change through its lifetime and thus such transmutation will run afoul of those assumptions.

Read more here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/transmutes.html

I am explaining thease because with the trait bound approach to accept different pointers, you'll will have to play a bit to match the correct one.
Also note that in the nomicon, it's talking about references. Trasmutting them like exposed above is *undefined behaviour.*
Casting pointers in this context it's always fine, but *dereferencing* them is a lot more complex. It may or not may lead to *undefined behaviour*, so you must take it carefully.

Comment: "Cast const things to mut ones is Undefined Behaviour" Wrong. Casting pointers is fine. Only transmuting references is UB.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman One thing. Casting pointers with the same type parameter, right? What's the difference then with transmutting a ptr? I mean, why refs are UB and not pointers?

Comment: _Any_ pointer casting is fine. As long as you don't deref them. If you do, well, that's another story.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman was assuming that the purpose is using the casts, so that's will be UB. But you're right. Will edit for clarification.

Comment: It still may not be UB, it is just a lot more involved.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman worth to explaining it, them